# Doing 301 redirect not just for a single page but for the whole site?

Tags: redirect

I would like to redirect my whole site to an homepage of another site. I know I could do this in javascript but I prefer to have the 301 Redirect for SEO reasons. How could I do this while mantaining the 301 redirect? At the moment I changed the .htaccess file with "Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/" but when someone type "olddomain.com/something/" instead of going into the homepage of the new site, they go to "newdomain.com/something/".

How can I fix this while mantaining the 301 redirect for SEO reasons?

Thanks in advance, Andrea

Comment: is this a salesforce question? i don't remember having .htaccess in Salesforce